# Unable to start my Apache Tomcat Server 6 on Windows 7 Platform

Tags: tomcat, windows-7

I am unable to start Apache Tomcat server 6 on Windows 7 32-bit Platform.I have installed JDk 1.7.0. While attempting so, it displays the following error message:

"Windows could not start the Apache Tomcat 6 on local computer. For more information review the system event log. Refer to server specific error code 0"

And when I tried to start the service form "Services(Local)", it says:

"Windows could not start the Apache Tomcat on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Evert Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 0"

And when go through the log file, it says:

"[174  javajni.c] [error] The specified module could not be found."

I have uninstalled and again installed the Tomcat Server many time but the problem still exists.
Please help.
Gaurav

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you get any messages in the actual system event log? I assume you don't mean that when you mention going through the log file...?

Comment: How exactly did you install Tomcat? Specifically, how did you install the service? Also, exactly which version of Tomcat are we talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an earlier version of JDK (1.6.x should be compatible)

Answer (score 0):

This also works!

cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin>Tomcat6